# Error in SQL Server when comparing two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a query here that selects the greatest value from two columns with dates and I get an error:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

What can I rewrite the query?

```
update Product
set date = (select 
                date1, date2,
                case when exists (date1 > date2 
                        then date1
                        else date2
                end as date))
            from Product))
```

Comment: Think about it: the sub-query returns **three** columns and you want to assign those three different values to a **single** column. What you essentially trying to do is: `set date = (1,2,3)` - doesn't make sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is no need to use other `Product` table in `UPDATE` if it is on the same row

```
UPDATE Product SET
    date = CASE WHEN date1 > date2 THEN date1 ELSE date2 END
```

Comment: This one is the answer, thank you so much. I'll check as an answer when the 3 minutes pass.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE Product
    SET date=(SELECT 
           CASE WHEN date1 > date2 THEN date1
                ELSE date2
           END AS date
           FROM Product
            )
```

Comment: This is going to fail with an error like "sub-query returned more then one row"

Comment: Obviously my answer is plain wrong.
Thank you for pointing out this :)